# Is it possible to create website shortcut programmatically on user's pc from a website?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I want to make it easy for users to just click the button and it should create a shortcut with website link to their desktop or mobile desktop so that they can visit the site by just clicking the shortcut.

I am not sure if it is possible to do so.

Comment: This question is possibly a duplicate. 
httpss://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509736/javascript-create-desktop-link-programmatically

Comment: yes but is it possible to click the button?

Comment: According to that link, the answer is no.